# How can create a shape like the image?

Tags: html, css, shapes, clip-path

How can I create mobile navigation like this image? There is a transparent gap down the logo.

[image]

Comment: checkout this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArTVfdHOB-M . this might help

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example